# RichTextBox Hyperlink color in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, hyperlink, richtextbox

I have an application that displays some text in a RichTextBox; I have some links in the text, so use `Hyperlinks` to display them.

My problem is that I can't get to set a color to the `Hyperlink` `Foreground` property. I know it can't pass it via `RichTextBox.Xaml` property; moreover, If i do

```
<RichTextBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" x:Key="HyperlinkColor">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
</RichTextBox.Resources>
```

nothing happens: the hyperlink remains stuck with the default color.

Is there a way to get the color I want on Hyperlinks in my RichTextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
        <RichTextBox>

            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkColorBrush"
                                 Color="White" />
            </RichTextBox.Resources>

            <Paragraph>
                <Hyperlink Foreground="{StaticResource HyperlinkColorBrush}">
                    Hi!
                </Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Hyperlink Foreground="{StaticResource HyperlinkColorBrush}">
                    How are you?
                </Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>

        </RichTextBox>
```

OR

**cs:**

```
        string xaml =
            @"<Section xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Hyperlink Foreground=""Green"">Hyperlink</Hyperlink>
                </Paragraph>
            </Section>";

        RichTextBox.Xaml = xaml;
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: You need <FlowDocument> tags and White Foreground is not a good choice.

Comment: I can't do this since I set the content programmatically. Thank you for the answer anyway :)

Comment: How you set the content programmatically? Can you give me some example?

Comment: RichTextBox box = new RichTextBox();
box.Xaml = @"<Section xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
                                <Paragraph>
                                   Hello World!
                                </Paragraph>
                            </Section>";

Comment: You can't do this because the Foreground tag is not allowed when passing Hyperlinks via XAML (at least, in Silverlight). It's explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Er, no. I've already tried this solution and doesn't work. I am working in Windows Phone, so it may work in WPF, but in WP this solution is useless.

Comment: @threddeveloper  I have tested it on physical device and it works perfect.

Comment: So, this is fairly odd. I did the same and it doesn't work, both on an emulator and a Nokia Lumia 620, using WP8 with latest updates. The OS seems to ignore the "Foreground" tag and uses always the default color.

Comment: @threddeveloper I have tested it on Nokia Lumia 920 with the last update "Lumia Black".

Comment: Ok, it was a problem in my code. I was taking the color from resources and the OS ignored it. Marked as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just set the foreground property like this:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.****.org" TargetName="_blank" Foreground="#FF337CBB">www.***.org</Hyperlink>
```

and it worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `x:Key` attribute from Style, so that it gets applied automatically to all hyperlinks which exists under RichTextBox.

```
<Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I fear that's because Hyperlink doesn't have the "Style" property in Silverlight. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @threddeveloper It is tagged WPF.  I hope you are not the person that voted this down.

Comment: My bad, I fixed the tag. No, I didn't downwote your answer, I learned something new anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem! And here's the solution that works:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkForegroundThemeBrush"
                             Color="TheColorYouNeed" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkPressedForegroundThemeBrush"
                             Color="TheColorYouNeed"/>
```